# Navigation bar color code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, classic-experience

It may be silly question, Please help me on this.

I have a site list with below navigation bar (Main menu).
Just wanted to make color code with boarder. Please help me on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to color the column headers in your list? Are you using modern experience or classic experience??

Comment: it is classic experience @Ganesh

Comment: Thank you, Can i make little design.

Comment: Please check my another attachment, Can i do like that ?

Comment: Check my updated answer below...I have pointed the required element selectors. You can add the CSS according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to apply CSS on each column header (`th` element) in your list view:

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr.ms-viewheadertr th {
        background-color: #003366 !important;
    }
    tr.ms-viewheadertr th * {
        color: white !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: where i will add the above CSS ?

Comment: Add CSS in Script editor or Content editor webpart and add the webpart by editing your list view page.

Comment: Thank you a lot Ganesh, You save my day.

Comment: Welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I have posted one more question,Can you please help me on that.

Comment: Sure, let me check it.